# Warn if invalid value for an enum is passed?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

If I have a function that takes an `enum` parameter, and I pass a literal that does not represent a valid enum member, can I get the compiler to emit a warning (gcc, clang, msvc?) Example code:

```
typedef enum {
    GPIO_0,
    GPIO_1,
    GPIO_2,
    GPIO_3
} gpio_t;

void gpio_set(gpio_t gpionum, uint8_t value) {
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    // I want a warning here because there is no 5 in gpio_t:
    gpio_set(5, 1);
}
```

Comment: No, that question is about confusing two *different* enums, which my have the same values. My question is about passing a number that is "invalid" for the wanted enum.

Comment: gcc 9.3.0 will throw a invalid conversion error for that, what compiler are you using?

Comment: clang has `-Wassign-enum`, gcc doesn't seem to have any option to enable such warnings.

Comment: @rmfeldt [nope](https://godbolt.org/z/eE6cqc39r).

Comment: Thanks, `-Wassign-enum` does the trick when using clang! (and `-Wenum-conversion` can tell you if you use an entry from a different enum)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ah, I compiled it as c++ code. my bad.

Comment: Please write an answer and mark it.

Comment: Why is this question closed? The linked questions are about runtime behavior and the posters had questions about the behavior of the language. Only accidentially do the answers mention `-Wassign-enum`. I think posting an answer here that I accept would be better for discoverability...